# Installing programs. Understanding Ubuntu. Command Prompt hard time

Tags: software-installation

I'm new to the whole Linux Ubuntu. I have to be honest...I have a hard time trying to install programs from outside the Software Center. Any tutorials recommendations on how to understand the command prompt and how to install from outside Ubuntu Software Center will be great. And by how to understand I mean the symbols, what they mean, what they execute, what to write for executions etc.
I like the fact that I'm stepping away from the mainstream softwares and I would like to keep self educating in Linux.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This question is too broad for this format. What software are you trying to install and what is the real problem?

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Answer (score 2):

Refer ubuntu community (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/),

1. help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal   --Use of Terminal
2. ubuntu-manual.org/downloads      ---Ubuntu manual
3. help.ubuntu.com/           --- Official Ubuntu Documentation
4. many more with google.com

Comment: Quoting the official documentation...  I would let that pass... @DavidFoerster  But as it's a duplicate Q, **following your lead!**